# import.io: get data from bulk extract

Tags: linux, bash, shell, import.io

I created an extractor on import.io and tested with couple of URL's, it's working.

Maybe this is a simple question, but how can I receive (fresh) data from CLI? I've spent several hours looking for the answer. I read the API manual, but there is no example for CURL (shell) method (and I think it's pretty complicated for a regular user).

I found a tool named bashtractor, that works (with multiple URL's), but it is creating multiple JSON root elements -> the result is an invalid JSON file.

https://github.com/import-io/bashtractor

Comment: If you only want the result for one URL, there's a [curl call](https://github.com/import-io/bashtractor/blob/master/bashtractor.sh#L30) example in the script you linked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just write a for loop, save json result to each file.

e.g.:

https://github.com/import-io/bashtractor/blob/master/bashtractor.sh
save json to `$DATA_FILE-$URL` instead of `$DATA_FILE`.

```
USER_GUID=$1
API_KEY=$2
EXTRACTOR_GUID=$3
URL_FILE=$4
DATA_FILE=$5

while read URL
do
    echo -n $URL
    curl -XPOST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -s -d "{\"input\":{\"webpage/url\":\"$URL\"}}" "https://api.import.io/store/connector/$EXTRACTOR_GUID/_query?_user=$USER_GUID&_apikey=$API_KEY" >> $DATA_FILE-$URL
    sleep 1
    echo " ...done"
done < $URL_FILE
```